# How to parse elements from a pandas row to a method to create new columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
In [282]: f
Out[282]: 
            Strike
01-02-2019   100.0
01-02-2019   105.0
01-02-2019   110.0
01-02-2019   115.0
01-02-2019   120.0
```

and I want to parse the entry from each position to a method and populate a new column like this:

```
def method(i,j):
    return(i,j)

for i,j in f.index, f.Strike: 
    f['newcol']=method(i,j)
```

but am receiving an error. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.items`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.items.html) in list comprehension:

```
df['new'] = [method(k, v) for k, v in df.Strike.items()]
```

Another solution with `zip`:

```
df['new'] = [method(k, v) for k, v in zip(df.index, df.Strike)]
```

Or use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: method(x.name, x.Strike), axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
            Strike                  new
01-02-2019   100.0  (01-02-2019, 100.0)
01-02-2019   105.0  (01-02-2019, 105.0)
01-02-2019   110.0  (01-02-2019, 110.0)
01-02-2019   115.0  (01-02-2019, 115.0)
01-02-2019   120.0  (01-02-2019, 120.0)
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Thanks.